# MATLAB count true values in an array but only one per group

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Given a logical array, A:

```
img = imread('coins.png'); %built-in coins.png demo image
A = img > 100;
```

I'd like a function that counts how many true elements are in the array, but ignore ones that are connected to one already counted. I expect it to return 10 for the example image above. My initial thought was to use something like erode / dilate, or one of the bwmorph functions, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

If the threshold was changed from 100 to 140, I would expect the function to return either 6 or 9 more depending on whether diagonals are considered to be connected.

Answer (score 2):

How about using [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html)

```
labelled = bwlabel(A);
max(A(:));
```

Answer (score 1):

The example here was very helpful:

http://au.mathworks.com/help/images/image-enhancement-and-analysis.html

```
cc = bwconncomp(A,4);
```

Produces an object containing the number of objects and their positions. When the threshold is 100, cc.NumObjects is 10. It depends on the connectivity, but for the second case (threshold is 140), the solution is 19 when connectivity is 8.